# How to draw a border around text in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a border for text, so it can tell user which object is selected.

The following example is a window with One Text and One Square, where Square is bordered with one red line.

[image]

So to draw a text is easy, because all I need is a font and a center point. But how to draw a border around a text?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to calculate text size to be able to draw a rectangle around it?

Comment: You may be able to do so with signed distance field font rendering

Comment: how about simply drawing the text with edge-detection shader?

Comment: @ALGOholic: This looks like `glutBitmapCharacter` drawn text, which uses old-and-busted OpenGL raster operations, which don't work with shaders.

Comment: @datenwolf lol in case you didn't notice dude, the entire program is shader based and it runs with WebGL which doesn't have any kind of old-style OpenGL functions. you're way out of your place making such comments as you obviously have not nearly enough expertise to be judging the problem or the solution.

Comment: @ALGOholic: Err, maybe I missed it, so could you please point me to the sourcecode of OP's program? Without seeing that I couldn't tell.

Comment: @ALGOholic: Or did you take my comment as a response to your shader code down below? Context dude, context.

Comment: the shader code below illustrates the comment above. context dude context. where did you take the glutBitmapCharacter idea from anyway?

Comment: @ALGOholic: The look of the text in OPs screenshot. That's very likely text produced using GLUT's glutBitmapCharacter function using the `GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13` bitmap font. I've been using OpenGL and its assorted libraries for so long now (about 20 years), I can often already tell by the look of certain elements in a screenshot, how a particular part of an image was produced. And shaders simply don't work with old-and-busted OpenGL raster drawing operations, which is what glutBitmapCharacter uses (they don't exist in WebGL, BTW).

Comment: he can easily move font drawing into shaders. they are supported in OpenGL and WebGL alike. focus on posting your answer, I don't have time for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try pasting the following on [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/new). It illustrates text border rendering via edge detection.

```
#define SC 0.07 // line scale
#define LW 0.03 // line width
#define C1 (vec2 p){return min(l(p,
#define C2 ),min(l(p,

// line segment
float l(vec2 p, float ax, float ay, float bx, float by)
{
    p = floor(p*500.+0.5)/500.;

    vec2 a = vec2(ax,ay)*SC;
    vec2 b = vec2(bx,by)*SC;
    vec2 ab = b-a;return length(p-a-ab*clamp(dot(p-a,ab)/dot(ab,ab),0.0,1.0))-LW;
}

float A C1 1.,-8.,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,5.,-5. C2 5.,-5.,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,5.,-5.),l(p,5.,-5.,5.,-8.))))));}
float B C1 4.,-5.,4.,-1.5 C2 4.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,5.,-8. C2 5.,-8.,5.,-5.),l(p,5.,-5.,1.,-5.))))));}
float C C1 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-8.),l(p,1.,-8.,5.,-8.)));}
float D C1 1.,-8.,4.,-8. C2 4.,-8.,4.5,-7.5 C2 4.5,-7.5,5.,-6.25 C2 5.,-6.25,5.,-3.75 C2 5.,-3.75,4.5,-2. C2 4.5,-2.,4.,-1.5 C2 4.,-1.5,1.,-1.5),l(p,1.,-1.5,1.,-8.))))))));}
float E C1 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,3.,-5. C2 3.,-5.,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,1.,-8.),l(p,1.,-8.,5.,-8.))))));}
float F C1 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,3.,-5. C2 3.,-5.,1.,-5.),l(p,1.,-5.,1.,-8.)))));}
float G C1 5.,-2.5,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,5.,-8. C2 5.,-8.,5.,-5.),l(p,5.,-5.,3.5,-5.))))));}
float H C1 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,5.,-5. C2 5.,-5.,5.,-1.5),l(p,5.,-1.5,5.,-8.)))));}
float I C1 1.5,-1.5,4.5,-1.5 C2 4.5,-1.5,3.,-1.5 C2 3.,-1.5,3.,-8. C2 3.,-8.,1.5,-8.),l(p,1.5,-8.,4.5,-8.)))));}
float J C1 1.5,-8.,3.,-8. C2 3.,-8.,4.,-7. C2 4.,-7.,4.,-1.5),l(p,4.,-1.5,1.5,-1.5))));}
float K C1 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,2.5,-5. C2 2.5,-5.,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,2.5,-5.),l(p,2.5,-5.,5.,-8.))))));}
float L C1 1.,-1.5,1.,-8.),l(p,1.,-8.,5.,-8.));}
float M C1 1.,-8.,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,3.,-4. C2 3.,-4.,5.,-1.5),l(p,5.,-1.5,5.,-8.))));}
float N C1 1.,-8.,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,5.,-1.5)));}
float O C1 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,5.,-1.5))));}
float P C1 1.,-8.,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,5.,-5.),l(p,5.,-5.,1.,-5.))));}
float Q C1 5.,-8.,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,3.5,-6.5)))));}
float R C1 1.,-8.,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,5.,-5. C2 5.,-5.,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,3.5,-5.),l(p,3.5,-5.,5.,-8.))))));}
float S C1 5.,-1.5,1.,-1.5 C2 1.,-1.5,1.,-5. C2 1.,-5.,5.,-5. C2 5.,-5.,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,1.,-8.)))));}
float T C1 3.,-8.,3.,-1.5 C2 3.,-1.5,1.,-1.5),l(p,1.,-1.5,5.,-1.5)));}
float U C1 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,5.,-1.5)));}
float V C1 1.,-1.5,3.,-8.),l(p,3.,-8.,5.,-1.5));}
float W C1 1.,-1.5,1.,-8. C2 1.,-8.,3.,-6. C2 3.,-6.,5.,-8.),l(p,5.,-8.,5.,-1.5))));}
float X C1 1.,-1.5,5.,-8. C2 5.,-8.,3.,-4.75 C2 3.,-4.75,5.,-1.5),l(p,5.,-1.5,1.,-8.))));}
float Y C1 1.,-1.5,3.,-5. C2 3.,-5.,3.,-8. C2 3.,-8.,3.,-5.),l(p,3.,-5.,5.,-1.5))));}
float Z C1 1.,-1.5,5.,-1.5 C2 5.,-1.5,3.,-5. C2 3.,-5.,1.,-8.),l(p,1.,-8.,5.,-8.))));}


void mainImage2( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{   
    float t = iGlobalTime;  
    vec2 uv = (2.0 * fragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.yy;

    uv.x += 0.13;
    uv.x *= abs(sin(uv.x+t*2.0)*0.5+1.0)+1.0;
    uv.y *= abs(sin(uv.x+t*2.0)+1.0)+1.0;

    vec3 col = vec3(0);
    float d = 1.0;

    d = min(d,S(uv-vec2(-2.0,0.5)));
    d = min(d,H(uv-vec2(-1.5,0.5)));
    d = min(d,A(uv-vec2(-1.0,0.5)));
    d = min(d,D(uv-vec2(-0.5,0.5)));
    d = min(d,E(uv-vec2( 0.0,0.5)));
    d = min(d,R(uv-vec2( 0.5,0.5)));
    d = min(d,T(uv-vec2( 1.0,0.5)));
    d = min(d,O(uv-vec2( 1.5,0.5)));
    d = min(d,Y(uv-vec2( 2.0,0.5)));

    col = mix(vec3(1),col,smoothstep(d,d+0.01,0.0));

    fragColor = vec4(vec3(1.-40.0*d),1.0);
}

#define DIST 0.005
#define ITR 5
#define THRESH 0.5

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{   
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    float x, y;
    vec4 neighborColor;
    float dist_sq;

    mainImage2(fragColor, fragCoord);

    for (int i = 0; i < ITR; i++) {
        x = mix(uv.x - DIST, uv.x + DIST, float(i) / float(ITR - 1));
        for (int k = 0; k < ITR; k++) {
            y = mix(uv.y - DIST, uv.y + DIST, float(k) / float(ITR - 1));
            dist_sq = pow(uv.x-x, 2.0) + pow(uv.y-y, 2.0);
            if (dist_sq < DIST * DIST) {
                mainImage2(neighborColor, vec2(x, y) * iResolution.xy);
                if (neighborColor.r > THRESH && fragColor.r < THRESH) {
                    fragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
                } else {
                    // fragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Several issues with this code. First and foremost it doesn't allow to load arbitrary fonts. Essentially the font is hardcoded into the shader in terms of distance fields against "stroke" functions. That's problematic for two reasons: First and formost the execution of those stoke distance evaluators takes GPU cycles and the way it's implemented it does this by testing each fragments's position against every line stroke. So for n fragment and m strokes this gives complexity O(n·m), i.e. O(n²). The other problem, though this can be solved by using several shaders is, that the string is hardcoded

Comment: it's supposed to illustrate edge detection. text generation method is immaterial. it was stated in the question that rendering a font is not a problem. therefore it can get into the shader in form of a texture. some imagination plz.

Comment: Yes, **I** can see that (in case you didn't notice I am the all-time opengl-tag top-answerer). But the code you dropped there is neither helpful for OP, nor for the occassional reader who Googles the problem, finds an answer on SO and then just sees a wall of source code without the slightest bit on information how it works. And OP very likely used some old-and-busted "draw text with GLUT" tutorial, has not the slightest clue how to use shaders. Likely OP giving your answer a try will somehow both a shader loader into his program, try loading it and be completely disappointed.

Comment: oh dear. that's a working solution and the way to learn. also with vector graphics making their way to GPUs (NV_path) it's totally top notch to push font rendering into shaders along with any outline/border effects and you know it. stop being jealous, post your answer and bugger off of mine.

Comment: Why should I be jealous? And no it's not a working solution in case OP uses glutBitmapCharacter or any other method for OpenGL bitmap font rendering.

Comment: he can easily move font drawing to shaders and keep using "old-and-busted" functions for other stuff. why would you imply otherwise if not because you're jealous. u jelly lol.

Comment: Because you're posting low quality answers. You don't really explain how and why this code works. You just drop a wall of source code and call it a day. This is poor quality for a site like SO.

Comment: It's basic shaders stuff. If OP has questions I will follow up. what's the matter with you dude - you should appreciate my time and focus on your own better answer. You're free to write an epos about that snippet if you'd like. Srsly find some productive occupation.